# How can I convert a DavkaWriter hebrew document to Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, conversion, encoding, hebrew

I have a DavkaWriter .doc file from 20 years ago. When it opens in Word it looks like this

[image]

This text should be
לא תרצח
לא תנאף

Does any one have any way of converting this? (I do not have access to a copy of the DavkaWriter software)

Apparently there is a program called DavkaReader which would do this, but this seems to no longer be available.
It seems that DavkaWriter uses its own proprietry format for Hebrew, so it does not seem possible to change the font, or to change the encoding.
I have tried to do a search and replace - assuming each symbol aligns with one Hebrew letter, but was not successful (perhaps because there is other encoding there, including vowel signs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DavkaViewer program download is still available from the
[WayBack machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20180107155810/http://www.davkawriter.com/viewer.html),
archived in 2018.
The DavkaViewer program itself is also available from
[this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180107155810/http://www.davkawriter.com/files/viewersetup.zip).

I have verified that I could download the program, but have not
tried to install it. The program itself dates from 2005,
so I don't know how well it will work today.

If the viewer doesn't work, note that the
[DavkaWriter website](https://davkawriter.com/)
still exists, but the software is quite costly.
You could ask them for help, or for a working DavkaViewer program.

Answer (score 1):

Using DavkaViewer, you can print the document as a PDF file. The issue then becomes that if you try and export it to Word from PDF all the Hebrew comes out backwards and I was unable to fix that issue.
HOWEVER.. If you want to edit in Word, simply open the document in DavkaViewer, open the Davka file, enter Control A to highlight the enter document and the simply copy and paste into a Word file. Works perfectly.
B'hatzlachah!
Yosef